# Simulate updates inside Firebase Database Simulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

My question is pretty simple, I don´t know how to simulate multiple updates inside Firebase Simulator. Since I don´t know how to even start I can´t provide any code. Any guidance will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to execute multi-location updates in the Firebase Database security rules simulator.

It would be great to have that functionality, so can you file a feature request for it [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)?

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response Puff :D