# Simulator shows no error in Firebase, but the permission is denied

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

These are my rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "username": {
      ".read": true,
          ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }
    },
    "usernames": {
      "$username": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val() == newData.parent().parent().child('users/' + auth.uid + '/username').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, in the simulator I see an error, but not what line the error occurs. I just see "write denied". When executing this in the simulator in XCode, I see "permission denied". I want to check if the given username is unique, that is all.

Edit:

Maybe I was not so clear. The simulator *does* shows an error, but not at which line. This was however my mistake. See picture 1: 
[image: Picture 1] I made a mistake at the path.

This is my second attempt, picture 2: 
[image: picture 2]

At picture 3 I added the error description:
[image: picture 3]

This goes wrong in the simulator, I can add the code from my project but I think the rules are not good.

Comment: Please edit your question to include 1) the code that fails and 2) a screenshot of the simulator that allows the same operation.

Comment: Yes I updated it with some pictures. Is it enough or should I post more? This is picture 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6lCg.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll treat the screenshots in turn:

1. In screenshot 1, you're trying to write to `/usernames`. Nobody has write permission on `/usernames` (only on specific nodes under it) so the write fails.
2. In screenshot 2, you're writing to `/usernames/myusername`. But the data you're writing violates the validation rule. What you're trying to write is a JSON object, while your rule only allows a simple string value. So you *could* write `"userUID"`, but you can't write `{ "hello": "userUID" }`.
3. In screenshot 3 you can see that your have write permission on that, as shown by the green checkmark next to the `.write` rules. But the `.validate` rule is rejecting the write, because it's checking for a string (and you're posting a JSON object).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the JSON to "something". This works for newData.isString(), however it not bypasses the second validation rule. See this picture: http://picpaste.com/plaatje4-sx4KLbXf.png I also changed the UID, so that is not the problem. What is wrong with the second rule?

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show enough information, because we can't see the existing data at `/users/...`. Keep in mind that the simulator in the Firebase Console cannot be used to simulate multi-location updates. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168377/simulate-updates-inside-firebase-database-simulator/40177926#40177926